# Error with NMaximize: "The following constraints are not valid" which disappears if the objective is changed

Tags: constraint, maximize

I am trying to optimize under constraint using `NMaximize`, however the constraints are flagged as invalid. I could not see the problem with the constraints so I tinkered with the objective without changing the constraints and then the problem disappeared (although of course it does not optimize using the intended objective). I could use some help towards pointing out the mistakes.

Here is the code:

```
NMaximize[{4/375 Sqrt[2] (2 - 25 x)^(3/2) + 2/375 (9 - 50 y)^(3/2), 
  1/10 <= y <= 4/25 && 
   0 <= x <= 1/25 Sqrt[9 - 50 y] + 1/25 (-3 + 25 y)}, {x, y}]
```

producing the error

```
NMaximize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid: {0<=x,1/10<=y,x<=1/25 Sqrt[9-50 y]+1/25 (-3+25 y),y<=4/25}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables.
```

However, replacing the objective with `x+y` produces no error:

````
NMaximize[{x + y, 
  1/10 <= y <= 4/25 && 
   0 <= x <= 1/25 Sqrt[9 - 50 y] + 1/25 (-3 + 25 y)}, {x, y}]

{0.24, {x -> 0.08, y -> 0.16}}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

- We test the result by `Maximize`.

```
Maximize[{4/375 Sqrt[2] (2 - 25 x)^(3/2) + 2/375 (9 - 50 y)^(3/2),    1/10 <= y <= 4/25 &&     0 <= x <= 1/25 Sqrt[9 - 50 y] + 1/25 (-3 + 25 y)}, {x, y}]
```

> `{32/375, {x -> 0, y -> 1/10}}`.

- I think the bug because of the power `^(3/2)`,here  we set `u == (2 - 25 x)^(3/2),  v == (9 - 50 y)^(3/2)` to overcome it.

```
NMaximize[{4/375 Sqrt[2] u + 2/375 v, u == (2 - 25 x)^(3/2), 
  v == (9 - 50 y)^(3/2), 1/10 <= y <= 4/25, 
  0 <= x <= 1/25 Sqrt[9 - 50 y] + 1/25 (-3 + 25 y)}, {x, y, u, v}]
```

> `{0.0853333, {x -> -5.00357*10^-10, y -> 0.1, u -> 2.82843, v -> 8.}}`

- Since it maybe a bug, we have to lift to higher dimensions to avoid this,that is why we introduce the variables `u,v`.

```
NMaximize[{4/375 Sqrt[2] u^(3/2) + 2/375 v^(3/2), u == (2 - 25 x), 
  v == (9 - 50 y), 1/10 <= y <= 4/25, 
  0 <= x <= 1/25 Sqrt[9 - 50 y] + 1/25 (-3 + 25 y)}, {x, y, u, v}]
```

> `{0.0853333, {x -> -7.71719*10^-10, y -> 0.1, u -> 2., v -> 4.}}`

Comment: Indeed this works, but it does not explain why the original tentative should fail, nor does it provide a simple fix (my objective is more complex than this, and although I could technically replace every single root by a variable, I would quite rather avoid it!).